# SPSS print to output on start

Tags: python, spss

I am looking for a way to print to the SPSS output on start of program. By looking in the [python documentation](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/25.0/en/client/Manuals/Python_Reference_Guide_for_IBM_SPSS_Statistics.pdf) for SPSS I cannot seem to find any instance for doing stuff on start. Or am I missing something here?

So after reading eli-k's comment ([startup scripts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/scripts_startup.html)) it should be as easy to place StartClient_.py in the /extensions directory but this does not seem to work as well..

```
#StartClient_.py
import SpssClient

SpssClient.StartClient()
print "whatever"
SpssClient.StopClient()
```

Comment: you should look up [spss startup scripts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/scripts_startup.html) (haven't used them myself but I think that should work for you)

Comment: Looks promising but I cannot get it to work. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Would `OUTPUT EXPORT` be helpful?  You can run this command at any time in your code and in combination with `OUTPUT CLOSE ALL` write many separate outputs to RTF or other formats.

Comment: hmmm.. I need a script placed in the /extensions directory to be run on every SPSS start.

Comment: Google Raynald's work:  Option Explicit 
Sub Main 
Dim objOutputDoc As ISpssOutputDoc 
Dim strParam As String 
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFileName As String

Set objOutputDoc=objSpssApp.NewOutputDoc

' ******** Change the next 2 lines as required
strPath  = "c:\\temp\\"
strFileName = "FileName.spo"

'Give path and file name to output document
objOutputDoc.SaveAs( strPath & strFileName)
'objSpssApp.OpenOutputDoc (strPath & strFileName)
'objOutputDoc.Close
'Set objOutputDoc=objSpssApp.GetDesignatedOutputDoc
'objOutputDoc.Visible=True
Set objOutputDoc=Nothing
End Sub